# Draggable box in Popup not working

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, popup, draggable

I need help on something. I try to put Draggable Box in Popup.
When I open popup in new tab, the box is draggable, but when don't open in new tab pop up the draggable popup don't working.

*Version Jquery : 1.7.2*

```
$(function() {
    $( "#emplacementPanier" ).draggable({ containment: ".top", scroll: false, cursor: "move"})
    $( "#divForLegend" ).draggable({ containment: ".top", scroll: false, cursor: "move"})
});
```

Comment: Does your popup exist when you apply this function or you append it to the DOM later. This function must be executed when `#emplacementPanier` and `#divForLegend` are already in the DOM. Before applying `.draggable()` try to `console.log($( "#emplacementPanier" )[0])` to see if the element exists.

Comment: Vote up if i helped ;)

Comment: Hi, I have test them with the code : `$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("ready!");
 console.log($("#emplacementPanier")[0]);
 console.log($("#emplacementPanier").length);
 $("#emplacementPanier").draggable({  scroll: false, cursor: "move"})


 //$("#emplacementPanier" ).draggable({ containment: ".top", scroll: false, cursor: "move"})
 //$("#divForLegend" ).draggable({ containment: ".top", scroll: false, cursor: "move"})
 console.log("fin ready!");
 });`   The result in console : `ready!`
`<div id="emplacementPanier">...</div>` `1 fin ready!`